# Execute simultaneous threads and notify when the last ends (Android Java)

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-safety

My program have:
One Activity
One heavy task to do when a button is pressed (with many threads cause are 10 download).
So when the button is presed I show a progress dialog and I do

```
onClick(){
  showDialog();
  for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
       download(i);   //download launches a new thread each call
  //wait without blocking the UI thread until last download end
       continue();
}
```

Whats the best and easier way of doing that? Thanks so much in advance

Answer (score 0):

You'll need references to all the `10` Thread objects. Say as an Array `Thread [] tasks`

so, you need to call the `join()` function to wait (blocking) for the thread to end.

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 10; i++)
      tasks[i].join();
```

Comment: thanks for your fast answer. But if i do it in the onClick() method it will block the UI right? how can i avoid it?

Comment: Instead of the the `onClick()`, have it execute in a thread. (pref. AsyncTask)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [CountDownLatch](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) or a [CyclicBarrier](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html).

You create the `CountDownLatch`, and initialize it with the number of threads you are starting, then pass it into each download thread. When the download thread is done its work, it calls `countDown` on the latch.

You can either call `await` on the latch from within the `onClick` method (but that will block that thread, which sounds like you don't want to do), or spawn one extra thread that simply calls `await`, blocking waiting for all of the download threads. Once the latch is opened, you can perform whatever actions you need to do (eg, take down the progress dialog).

```
final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(10);
for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
    download(i, latch);

Thread cleanup = new Thread( new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try{
            // This will block
            latch.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e ) {
            // TODO
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        takeDownDialog();
        whateverElseYouNeedToDo();
    }
});
cleanup.start();
```